# How to change process.env variable using dotenv in client side based on staging or production?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, create-react-app

I'm trying to change a socket domain based on whether the website is in development, staging, or production.

In order to do it, I need to be able to change the `REACT_APP_SOCKET_DOMAIN` variable inside `process.env`.

So far:
1. I've been basing what's inside the `process.env` variable on the `.env.development` and `.env.production` file in the client side which is using the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) npm package.
2. I think I need to use a separate `.env.test` file, but I'm not sure how to change the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to something other than *production* or *development*.

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)